# How to setup JsonWritter for ext.net store

Tags: crud, ext.net

I cannot find the solution for configuring ext.net restful store. Reading and deleting records works good, but I need also update and create functionality. For this I need to send data to WCF (restful) service in Json or XML format. In classic ExtJS I would create a store with JsonWritter, but how to do that in ext.net ? Store doesn't have public property Writter (or similar), so I cannot use ... markup. I also didn't find a way how to set writter later (on the place like Ext.onReady...).

Of course, I can gather all data and call WCF service directly (ajax) and then just refresh the store.
But that is not that nice like it would be when store handles all CRUD operation by itself.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Please investigate the following sample
http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Restful/Overview/

Comment: Hello. Thank you, but I know this example, it works, but the only problem I have is that data uploaded to server via POST call is not in JSON format (fiddler: data=%7B%22Id%22%3A-4%2C%22Email%22%3A%22sdfsdf%22%2C%22First%22%3A%22sdfs%22%2C%22Last%22%3A%22dfsdf%22%7D). If I can setup JsonWriter it will work the way I need :)